# Java substring out of range: -1

Tags: java, substring

I'm a new member on Stackoverflow but I've been reading here before to help me with my first steps on Java. I'm currently a student in college so I don't have any in-depth knowledge more than if, loop and array for now.

I'm currently working on a fonction but i've been stagnant for the last few days. I'm stuck with this substring that refuse to work.

I feel kinda foolish asking for help because i'm sure its a error that everybody could see in 2 seconds but I can't put my finger it... Anyway I usually wouldn't have asked but I need to hand it over in a couple of days so...

here it goes:

The input is a texte file but the ligne = fichier.substring cut it to this:
Evariste Galois,3,7.5,8.5,10.0,5.5,2.5,0.0,3.4

```
private static String fabriquerRapport(String input) 

{
    String output = input;
    double tauxHoraire = 15.65;
    double tauxAugmentation = 0.015;

    String nom = "";
    int ancien = 0;
    double lundi = 0;
    double mardi = 0;
    double mercredi = 0;
    double jeudi = 0;
    double vendredi = 0;
    double samedi = 0;
    double dimanche = 0;
    String ligne = "";
    String fichier = output;
    String chaine = "";
    int indice = ligne.indexOf(",");

    double reg = 0;
    double supp = 0;
    double total = 0;

    java.util.Calendar c = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
    String date = String.format("%1$tY-%1$tm-%1$te %1$tH:%1$tM",c);

    output  = "================================================================================================\n" ;
    output += "RGT Media : Rapport de charge salariale                           Comptable : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n" ;
    output += "Date      : " + date +"\n";
    output += "================================================================================================\n" ;
    output += "                           A   L    M    M    J    V    S    D       Reg.      Supp.    Salaire \n" ;
    output += "================================================================================================\n" ;

    ligne = fichier.substring(0 , fichier.indexOf("\n"));
    nom = ligne.substring(0,indice);
    if(nom.length()>27) nom = nom.substring(0, 23) + "...";
    ligne = ligne.substring(indice+1);
    output += nom;

    return output;
}
```

Don't mind the unused variable, there is more but I deleted a lot of it for this post since most of it is in commentary because i'm blocked here. Sorry the variable are in french but I guess you're still able to understand what they're doing.

The problem is ligne.substring at nom. It should take the String from the beginning of the String to the indice wich is the indexOf "," but it give me a java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String out of range: -1 error and I really can't seems to find out why. I usually find solution for my problem by searching online but not this time. I've been really tired lately so maybe thats why I can't find the solution to this :P but i'm really stuck so please guys, I need your help!

Thanks TheBigBang914

Comment: Are you sure it's not because `fichier.indexOf("\n")` returns `-1` (not found)? Remember that `BufferedReader.readLine()` and `Scanner.nextLine()` don't return the newline characters.

Comment: yes I'm sure its not from `fichier.indexOf("\n")` because I did a `output += ligne;` and I received the line that I pasted before my code wich is exactly what I wanted to receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about these three lines:

```
int indice = ligne.indexOf(",");
...
ligne = fichier.substring(0 , fichier.indexOf("\n"));
nom = ligne.substring(0,indice);   // exception here (you say)
```

If you are getting:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String out of range: -1
```

it is clearly telling you that you are using `-1` as one of the bounds.  Clearly, the first bound is zero, but you are using the result of `indexOf` as the second bound.  If `indexOf` cannot find the required string, it returns `-1`.

So the cause of your problem is a line that DOES NOT contain a `","`.

---

There are also problems with the logic of the previous lines.

1. If `fichier` doesn't have a newline at all, the previous line will throw an exception.
2. If `fichier` uses a different line-separator sequence (e.g. `"\r\n"` (Windows) or `"\r"` (Mac)), then various things could happen.
3. If `fichier` contained multiple lines, and first line did not a comma, then the line trimming would REMOVE the characters that the `indexOf(",")` call found, and the the subsequent `ligne.substring(0, indice)` would fail.

This is all a bit hypothetical, because we don't know what input your `fabriquerRapport` is likely to encounter.  However, clearly it is getting unexpected input ... so it would be advisable to make it more robust.

---

**UPDATE**

Actually, while all of the above is valid.  I think that the REAL problem, is that you are parsing the wrong string.  Look at how `ligne` is initialized.  Surely, you should initialize it to `input` ... not `""` !!!

Comment: Your points are really good but first: I know that an out of bound -1 means that there is no "," in my String but I tried to do a output += ligne and I received the answer I was expecting, the same line I pasted before my code wich does contain a comma. Secondly, it is suppose to contain a loop where it should exit the loop when there is no more line but i'm not done, I want to fix this problem first than continue working on it. Third, the input file is created automaticaly in a controled environment by a program so it should always encounter same format.

Comment: Sorry I only saw your update after a while. Does it really matter? because I initialized it at `ligne = fichier.substring(0 , fichier.indexOf("\n"));` and it seems to work fine until it reach `nom = ligne.substring(0,indice);` .

Comment: Yes it does matter.  Look at how `indicier` is calculated.  Seriously though, what you are doing there is a convoluted mess. You should tidy it up **even if it worked**.

Comment: Thank god I didn't show you everything that was in commentary. :P I'm real good at complicating my own life in coding. Hell I once did a project in 10 lines and my professor showed me how to do it in 3... anyway I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: Its working! I initialized indice after I told him what ligne was. Thanks you my good man. Like I said at the top I knew it was an easy mistake but I couldn't find it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of `fichier.indexOf("\n")`this returns -1. Based of the code looks like you want to separate the string fichier into lines. you can use split to do this.

```
String[] lines = string.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Comment: I've never used .split before but maybe i'll try it tomorrow. Like i said somewhere else, it all work fine until I reach `nom = ligne.substring(0,indice);`. It even show the line if I do a `output += ligne;`, so I doubt `fichier.indexOf("\n")` is my problem.

Comment: Than int indice = ligne.indexOf(","); is the problem. That statement will return -1 in indice. print the value of indice and check. And when you try to find substring with index as -1 it will show an exception.

Comment: I think I found out why it didn't work. I initialized indice with ligne.index before telling him what ligne was. God my code is a mess, like always... I'll try that.

Comment: Yup that was my mistake. Thank you! Always the smallest mistake that are the harder to find.

Answer (score 0):

int indice = ligne.indexOf(","); is the problem. That statement will return -1 in indice. print the value of indice and check. And when you try to find substring with index as -1 it will show an exception.

Comment: Yes I know, thats what I commented under your other comment.

Comment: I've already accepted Stepehn C answer because you both found it a the same time and I can't accept two answer.

Comment: No problem. Important thing is that we could help!